# Matlab tcpclient function error

Tags: matlab, tcpclient, tcp

trying to use matlab tcp communication feature. When i use `t = tcpclient('169.254.131.130', 10300)` i get `Undefined function 'tcpclient' for input arguments of type 'char'`. Even i try to use the same function as `tcpclient(host,port)` i still get same error.I use the function from https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tcpip-communication.html. What is the problem? In website it says this function is used in this configuration type.

Comment: Are you using an older version of matlab? Try running `help tcpclient` to see if the function exists in your matlab version.

Comment: As Trogdor mentioned, this might not work if your MATLAB version is too old (that is, before **2014b**). If this is the case, you might want to try [`tcpip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpip.html). See comparison [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/283275-difference-between-tcpclient-and-tcpip).

Comment: Yeah it is 2014a thank your for helping i will upgrade it